# $\mathbb{R}^n$ without finitely many points are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am kind of stuck when dealing with the following question:

> Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be two finite sets with $|A|=|B|$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus B$.

My attempt is to seek a continuous bijection between these two metric spaces and try to show that the inverse function is also continuous. However, I am stuck in the first step.

Thanks.

Comment: Start with the easy cases and build up to the hard cases. Can you do $n=1$? How about $n=2$?

Comment: When you take a subset off, you actually take points off from the whole space, so start from proving that your statement hold for $|A|=|B|=1$.

Comment: @KevinSong: I don't understand.

Comment: @KevinSong I see how it should work if $|A|=1$ or $|A|=2$, but do you mind elaborating on how we could proceed from $|A| = n$ to $|A| = n+1$? My thought would be taking a function that is the homomorphism that maps the first $n$ points together and then moves the last point somehow. But I am stuck here.

Comment: @HaoboLi I posted an answer below, I think you misunderstood my comment, it's not necessary to use induction here. I just want to lead you to think about what you're actually doing when taking those points off, see my answer below, hope that could give you a clearer view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment, it doesn't mean you need to use induction, in fact, it's useless here. I think you can find that when you take those point off, you're actually restricting the map to focus on those points and map them to the range continuously and then take them off. If you found that, the following process would be quite obvious. And I'm sorry for replying so late.

---

Let $A=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}$ those points need to be removed, but let's don't remove it now. and $B=\{y_1,y_2,...y_k\}$ the range set.

First, define a continuous map $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $f(A)=B$ (i.e. we map the point $x_i$ to $y_i$). We set $f$ to be a **homeomorphism** $\implies$ $f$ is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse. We can set that because there exists a whole bunch of continuous bijections that satisfy our criterion.

Define $\bar{f}:\Bbb{R}^n\setminus A\to \Bbb{R}^n,\bar{f}(x)=f(x)$ then $\bar{f}$ is continuous because it's the composite of the inclusion map $i:\Bbb{R}^n\setminus A\to \Bbb{R}^n$ and $f$, both of which are continuous.

A similar argument shows that $f^{-1}|_{\Bbb{R}^n\setminus f(A)}$ is also continuous.

Combine the information above, we get the restriction map $\bar{f},\bar{f}^{-1}$ which are continuous and bijective (directly followed by $f$ is bijective).

Thus $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus A\cong\Bbb{R}^n\setminus B,$ if $|A|=|B|<\infty$.

---

**Extension:**

Can you manage to show that if $g:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, and $A\subset X$ being given the subspace topology, then $X\setminus A\cong Y\setminus g(A)$? Using exactly the same method mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You may assume that the $x$-coordinates of all the points in a given set ($A$ or $B$) are different $-$ if they are not, just choose a different direction as your $x$-axis. So now you can order the points, and match each point $a_i\in A$ with a point $b_i\in B$. Now your bijection will use an 
appropriate shear transformation to map the horizontal region between $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ to the corresponding horizontal region between $b_i$ and $b_{i+1}$, with $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ mapping to $b_i$ and $b_{i+1}$ respectively.

I hope this is clear. If not, let me know.

Comment: Can you add some information in your post about how one can choose a coordinate system that will ensure distinct x-coordinate values?

Comment: @Arin: I realise that what I stated originally is not true if $A$ and $B$ have points in common. I have edited my answer to clear this up. So now: Step (i): choose a direction $v$ that is not parallel to any of the line segments from one point to another point in the same set. This is easy, as there are only a finite number of such line segments but an infinite number of directions. Step (ii): choose your $x$-axis to be perpendicular to $v$. (Neither of these steps is possible if $n=1$, but in that case all the points have different $x$-coordinates to start with.)

Comment: @TonyK: I think what you wrote is a clear view of how the bijection would look like. I guess you are saying that we could use a shear transformation to both rotate $a_i$s and expand them by a factor of $\frac{\|b_i\|}{\|a_i\|}$. Am I understanding it correctly? If so, the angle to rotate and the factor to expand should be continuously changing as we move from $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$, and I wonder if there is a way to express this in a formula.

Comment: @HaoboLi: you don't need to rotate. And the expansion factor doesn't change continuously, it changes discontinuously at each $a_i$. (But the transformation itself is continuous.) Expressing this as a formula would not help, in my opinion.